# Regex difference

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone explain why

```
text.replaceAll("\\W|\\d|\\s+", " ");
```

and

```
text.replaceAll("\\W|\\d", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

are different? In the first example the text doesn't remove more than 1 spaces and in the second example - it removes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.replaceAll` method parses the string only once, and `\W` contains already `\s`. That is why the branch `\s+` is never tested in your first code (the first branch on the left wins).

In the second code, the whole string is parsed an other time with `\s+`.

Comment: Thanks, but when \s+ is the first one, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Helosze: obviously since all `\W` and digits characters are not already replaced with spaces. To obtain the same result in one pass, use `[\\W\\d]+`

Comment: ok, but the situation is - text[space][space][space]text - that 3 spaces shouldn't be changed into one space by \s?

Comment: @Helosze: No, as I explained in my answer, `\\W` will match each spaces (one by one) and since the `\\W` branch succeeds, the `\\s+` branch is never tested. *(the first on the left wins)*

Comment: If you put `\\s+` in the first branch, this branch will succeed and your three spaces are replaced with a single space. But there's always an important difference with your second code. In your second code, the part `text.replaceAll('\\W|\\d', ' ')` creates a new string with new spaces characters that are matched with the second part `.replaceAll('\\s+', ' ')`

Comment: And it doesn't work when \s if the first and I don't know why. :) But nevermind, [\W\d]+ is that what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Helosze: I haven't the time now, but I will try to add a better and more detailed explanation later in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first example \W takes each space (thus \s+ does not) and replaces it with a space.
That still happens in the second example, but \s+ now acts separately after \W|\d and folds many-spaces into a single space char.

try text.replaceAll("[\\W\\d\\s]+"," ")

Answer (score 1):

Your first example: `\W|\d|\s+` matches:

- one non-word character  (`\W`)
- OR one digit character (`\d`)
- OR one-or-more spaces (`\s+`)

It's a lazy OR, so each ' ' matches the `\W`, and gets replaced by a .

Perhaps you want `(\W|\d|\s)+`, in which the whole group is repeated. However here the `\s` is redundant, since it's included in `\W`.

For single characters, it's usually simpler to use a *character class* rather than `|`:

```
[\W\d]+.
```

Answer (score 0):

**REGEXP:**

```
\w <= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] and whitespace
\d <= numbers
\s+ {
\s <= whitespace
+ <= 1 or more...
}
```

**Example: (+)**

```
\w+ <= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] and whitespace(1 or more)
\d+ <= numbers(1 or more)
```

**Result: for "\w+"**

```
hello123 => hello
```

**Result: for "\d+"**

```
hello123 => 123
```

**Result: for "\w+\d+"**

```
hello123 => hello123
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

`\W` means any non-word character (`[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`), which includes white-space.

Therefore in your first pattern, the `\s+` part is redundant: It matches any single white-space character and replaces it with `" "`. The `replaceAll` method  in Java parses the string only once.